# Flex Mobile persist view data

Tags: actionscript-3, air, flash-builder, flex4.5, flex-mobile

I built a simple hello world app to check out the Flash Builder 4.5 mobile capabilities.

Here's how it works:

The Default View asks for name in an textinput and has a continue button

When you click the continue button it pushes a new view in the viewNavigator which just displays "Hello " + name in a label.

When you click anywhere in this view, it pops a view (i.e. itself) from the viewNavigator, to go back to the default view

I see only 1 issue with this:
When I get back to the default view, it is in its initial state, i.e. the textInput is blank. It seems as if the viewNavigator created a new view of the default view's class and pushed this, instead of just removing the top view and displaying the previous one.

I see this being especially problematic for programs which display data in a grid and you can click the data to view the detail...when you get back, the grid will be empty.

Any ideas or gotchas to solve this?

EDIT:
Project name: HelloWorld
Code below:

**HelloWorldDefaultView.mxml**

```
protected function button1_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void {
    navigator.pushView(HiView, tName.text);
}
```

HiView.mxml

```
protected function view1_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void {
    navigator.popView();
}

protected function view1_creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void {
    lblHello.text="Hello " + data;
}
```

Screenshots

[image: Initial screen]
Initial screen

[image: Screen 2]
Screen 2

[image: Clicking on screen 2 gets us back to initial screen. Notice the blank textInput]
Clicking on screen 2 gets us back to initial screen. Notice the blank textInput

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to set [destructionPolicy="never"](http://devgirl.org/2011/05/18/flex-4-5-mobile-data-handling/) and then

```
protected function button1_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void {
    data = tName.text;
    navigator.pushView(HiView, tName.text);
}
```

to store the data in current View's data - before changing to another one?

Comment: Would it be better (from a memory point of view) to store the data in a static variable and create the view each time, or to set `destructionPolicy="never"`?

Comment: I've done both too. With static variable you'll probably save few bytes, but the other solution looks more "object oriented"

Answer (score 1):

That's the way it is supposed to work for mobile applications.

Check out this article: [Flex 4.5 (Hero) – Persistant Data in MobileApplication](http://custardbelly.com/blog/2010/11/15/flex-hero-persistant-data-in-mobileapplication/)

As they write:

> Each time a View is removed from the display list (via popView() or pushView()) its instance is destroyed, but its data model is stored in memory.
>
> In order to save session state for a View, you must modify the data property. This property will be requested when destroying the current instance of the View class. And the data property value will be assigned back to a newly created instance of the same View class when navigating back to that view.

Comment: This is weird.  
So everytime I want to go back to the previous view, I have to rebuild it?  
Any workaround to this?

Comment: There is a destructionPolicy attribute that you can set to false.
Check out http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/flexsdk/View+and+ViewNavigator

"By default, this will be set to ContainerDestructionPolicy.AUTO, meaning that views should be destroyed immediately after removal. If set to ContainerDestructionPolicy.NEVER, the view will remain in memory. This property is useful to use if a developer knows that a view takes a particularly long time to instantiate or if the developer doesn't want to lose the content in the views."

Comment: yup, @Alexander's answer put it nicely. Thanks for your help :)